# Get text of selected items in a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to  show the selected items of listBox1 in a Message Box here's the code:

```
int index;
string  item;
foreach (int i in listBox1 .SelectedIndices )
{
    index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    item = listBox1.Items[index].ToString ();
    groupids = item;
    MessageBox.Show(groupids);
}
```

The problem is that when I select more than one item 
the message box shows the frist one I've selected and repeats the message 
EX: if I selected 3 items the message will appear 3 times with the first item

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `i` in the foreach loop has the index you need. You're using `listBox1.SelectedIndex` which only has the first one. So item should be:

```
item = listBox1.Items[i].ToString ();
```

Answer (score 15):

You can iterate through your items like so:

```
        foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

How about 1 message box with all the selected items?

```
List<string> selectedList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems) {
   selectedList.Add(item.ToString());
}
if (selectedList.Count() == 0) { return; }
MessageBox.Show("Selected Items: " + Environment.NewLine +
        string.Join(Environment.NewLine, selectedList));
```

If any are selected, this should give you a line for each selected item in your message box. There's probably a prettier way to do this with linq but you didn't specify .NET version.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
string  item = "";    
foreach (int i in listBox1.SelectedIndices )
    {
       item += listBox1.Items[i] + Environment.NewLine;
    }
MessageBox.Show(item);
```

Comment: I like this answer because it gives one easy access to the index and the value.