# How to get the text of selected items in listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get the selected items text from my listbox as you can see in the image bellow:
[image]

But I only can get the type of the selected item as you can see in the next picture:

[image]

This is my code that gets the selected item to string

```cs
String selectedPackage = "";
foreach (object packages in packageListBox.SelectedItems)
{
    selectedPackage += (selectedPackage == "" ? "" : "\n") + packages.ToString();
}
```

Is there any way to get the actual "Test123" and "Test321" text to string ?

Comment: type cast your `packages` variable to `WPF.Models.Package` and then you should be able to access it's properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get text of selected items in a ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614157/get-text-of-selected-items-in-a-listbox)

Comment: Can you share your xaml and `Package` model?

Comment: The answer below did the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LINQ Select method to get a collection of strings from a collection of Packages. Then join the strings:

```
string selectedPackages = string.Join("\n",
    packageListBox.SelectedItems.Cast<Package>().Select(p => p.PackageText));
```

Replace `PackageText` with whatever the actual text property is.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are grabbing string representation of your model object which is in your case `Package`. You could do something like below to extract the selected items of ListBox before accessing the required property package instance.

```
String selectedPackage = "";
foreach (object packages in packageListBox.SelectedItems)
   {
      var package = packages as Package
      if (package !=null)
       {
          //You can now use package object to extract the property you want.
       }
   }
```

Comment: Better then using `as`, use an explicit cast like `var package = (Package)packages;`. You would thus correctly get an InvalidCastException if for whatever reason a selected item is not a Package.

Comment: That's correct. But the idea of having 'as' is to capture both invalid cast and null. That is, if there exist a null as a list element. 'as' will make sure the scenario you listed and a possible null.

Comment: The SelectedItems collection never contains null items. Even if it would, an explicit cast would still work. Using the `as` operator would be even more pointless then. It's actually just a bad habit to always use `as` where an explicit cast would be appropriate.

Comment: @Clemens, Please note your answer may cause an ArgumentNullException source (bounded instance) is null. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Why do you think that? The SelectedItems property is never null. And if you think that, why does your code not handle that case?

Comment: I am referring to the selected item ( object of Current from Enumerator) not selected items ( Enumerable). If you still think, there is no substance for my point, please ignore.

Comment: The exception you are referring to is thrown when `source` is null, i.e. `SelectedItems` here. And as already said, there are never any null elements in SelectedItems, so you don't need to handle that case.